# Clicking on search button and grid row not working on Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, button, xpath

Take a look at this:

[image]}

i got this error message:

```
element click intercepted: Element <button class="action-submit" type="button" data-bind="click: apply.bind($data, false)">...</button> is not clickable at point (393, 361). Other element would receive the click: <div data-role="spinner" data-component="product_listing.product_listing.product_columns" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">...</div>
xpath: //*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button]
```

---

The SEARCH ICON has this:

```
<button class="action-submit" type="button" data-bind="click: apply.bind($data, false)">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Search'">Search</span>
    </button>
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button
```

And then, i click on the grid and it has this:

```
<td data-bind="css: getFieldClass($row()), click: getFieldHandler($row()), template: getBody()">
<div class="data-grid-cell-content white-space-preserved" data-bind="html: $col.getLabel($row())">HISENSE 32"</div>
</td>
```

And XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]
```

I did this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]")).click();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Post the URL to have a look

Comment: There's no exposed url